# Poisson related homework question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

The number of new cars sold by a dealer each week is distributed as a Poisson variable
with mean 10. Suppose that 80% of the customers need a loan to pay for the car,
and of these 62.5% are likely to take the loan from the dealer. Suppose that the loan
amounts are on average 22,000, with a standard deviation of 5,000. Find the
approximate probability that the total new car loan issued by the dealer in one week will exceed 600,000.

Here is where I am. Let $N$ be the number of cars sold and $N~P(10)$. Let $L$ be a random variable representing the loan amount. We want to compute $P(0.8\times0.625\times N\times L>600,000)$. $N$ and $L$ times together. How to resolve this? Please help!!!

Comment: are the loan amounts normal? "the loan amounts are on average 22000 wihth sd of 5000"

Comment: @Jellyfish This is the part I am struggling with. There is no info. about L expect mean and std:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of loan takers *N* will be distributed $N\sim\text{Poisson}(10\cdot .8 \cdot .625)=\text{Poisson}(5)$.

The cost of the loan (assuming a normal distribution) will be $L|N\sim\text{Normal}(22000N, (5000N)^2)$.

The probability that the loans will exceed 600000 is

$$\begin{split}P(L>600000)&=\sum_{N=0}^\infty P(L>600000|N)P(N)\\
&=\sum_{N=0}^\infty P(Z>\frac{600000-22000N}{5000N})P(N)\\
&=\sum_{N=0}^\infty \Phi(\frac{22000N-600000}{5000N})\frac{e^{-5}5^N}{N!}\end{split}$$

The prob stabilizies after about N=25 to be $2.369295e-07$